# How to change the port on which GeoServer 2.13 runs on when it is installed as platform independent binary on Linux

Tags: geoserver

Note this question IS NOT about how to change Tomcat port or jetty port or Mac or Windows native installation of GeoServer. Each configuration for different platform is different. I tried many different ways to change port to 8585 from default 8080 but it ignores my changes and still gets launched on 8080. I tried changing startup.sh and added -Djetty.port=8585 in the exec part and tried jetty-http.xml but nothing works.

I am not surprised this is not documented anywhere on their manual.

Comment: The platform independent binary is just jetty running GeoServer so you need to follow the normal instructions for Jetty.

Comment: The GeoServer team welcome documentation fixes - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/introduction/gettinginvolved.html#documentation

Comment: i have a similar problem also with jetty and geoserver, i try this, but not working, let me explain, this is when i install the "ImageI/O-Ext GDAL" extension for ecw image format, also this happen when xamp is installed that means tomcat or some other is using the 8080 port, if i install on a clean machine it just jworks, but not where is xamp; i have tried to change to port 8090 on this files: wrapper/wrapper.conf; etc/jetty.xml ; star.ini; the problem is geoserver admin page start, but on log show this: geoserver log: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDY3M.png)](htt

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146921)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All you do is edit the line in `start.ini` that says:

```
jetty.port=8080
```

to:

```
jetty.port=8585
```

start GeoServer up `./bin/start.sh` or `.\bin\start.bat` and away you go.

Comment: Ian I did exactly as you said but it did not work. same issue starts at 8080. I had to create start.ini as it dd not exist in geoserver_home/bin

Comment: start.ini is in geoserver not bin

Answer (score 0):

I just suffer from same issue. I installed the geoserver as service and found the solution on email list. Just want to paste the same thing here,

I assume you have GeoServer installed as a service.
Altering the default port in jetty.xml didn't help because as I found out
the port number is hardcoded into the service path. To change the port
number Geoserver 2.1 is running on you need to do the following:

- stop your running GeoServer 2.1.0-service
- open regedit
- locate the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM
  CurrentControlSet\Services\GeoServer 2.1.0
- modify the key entry named ImagePath. At the end of this key you will see
  the phrase âDjetty.port=8080â (or whatever port number you have chosen in
  the installer). Change this to âDjetty.port=8090â.
- close regedit
- restart your GeoServer 2.1.0-service. Your Geoserver installation will
  now run on port 8090.